# Strange behavior with absolute positioning, style.top, style.left and "a" tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, tooltip

I was trying to complete a simple task on Javascript.info and I'm getting my ass beaten by an "a" tag. The task is to simply place (and remove) a tooltip above the element on hover and I have no problem with the roof or the house, but when I try to place the box above the link, it breaks and I can't solve it for my life.

I'm asking for help here because the solution on the site uses position:fixed while I'm trying to use position:absolute and simply mimicking the solution won't help me learning anything. The problem is all on line 77 and 78, when I try to assign tooltip.style.left and tooltip.style.top.

If I try to assign it usign a literal (for example, "-58px"), it works. Otherwise, it just defaults to whatever value the tooltip on "house" would have. I tried to see what is going on with some *tactical* alerts and it drove me insane. It shows me that if I use a computed value, it defaults and if I use a literal, it will work normally.

I'd like someone to explain what is going on and possibly some insight (pointing out if I got wrong how position:absolute works, how element size properties works or something on this nature)

The code (I only made the part that is inside of the script tag on line 64, the rest is from the authors of the task):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      height: 2000px;
      /* the tooltip should work after page scroll too */
    }

    .tooltip {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 100;

      padding: 10px 20px;

      border: 1px solid #b3c9ce;
      border-radius: 4px;
      text-align: center;
      font: italic 14px/1.3 sans-serif;
      color: #333;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }

    #house {
      margin-top: 50px;
      width: 400px;
      border: 1px solid brown;
    }

    #roof {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 200px solid transparent;
      border-right: 200px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 20px solid brown;
      margin-top: -20px;
    }

    p {
      text-align: justify;
      margin: 10px 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div data-tooltip="Here is the house interior" id="house">
    <div data-tooltip="Here is the roof" id="roof"></div>

    <p>Once upon a time there was a mother pig who had three little pigs.</p>

    <p>The three little pigs grew so big that their mother said to them, "You are too big to live here any longer. You must go and build houses for yourselves. But take care that the wolf does not catch you."</p>

    <p>The three little pigs set off. "We will take care that the wolf does not catch us," they said.</p>

    <p>Soon they met a man. <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Little_Pigs" data-tooltip="Read on…">Hover over me</a></p>

  </div>
  <script>
    house.onmouseover= function(event){
      let target= event.target.closest('[data-tooltip]');

      let tooltip= document.createElement('div');
      tooltip.textContent= target.dataset.tooltip;
      tooltip.classList.add("tooltip");
      target.append(tooltip);

      if(!tooltip.parentElement.style.position){
        tooltip.parentElement.style.position= 'relative';
      }
      tooltip.style.position= 'absolute';
      tooltip.style.top= "-"+(tooltip.offsetHeight+5)+"px";
      tooltip.style.left= -target.clientLeft+(target.offsetWidth-tooltip.offsetWidth)/2+"px";
      
      //alert("-"+(tooltip.offsetHeight+5)+"px");
      //alert(tooltip.style.top);
    }
    house.onmouseout= function(event){
      let target= event.target.closest('[data-tooltip]');
      tooltips= target.querySelectorAll('.tooltip');
      for(tooltip of tooltips){
        tooltip.remove();
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks already :)

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to place the box above the link, it breaks

This is because the tooltip box is positioned to appear under the mouse. Hovering over the link generates a regenerative feedback loop of

1. Create and append the tooltip element to the `<a>` element
2. The mouse is over the tooltip element
3. Fire `mouseout` on the `a` element in preparation of firing `mouseover` on the tooltip.
4. `mouseout` handling removes the tooltip element
5. The mouse is now over the `a` element,
6. Fire `mouseover` on the `a` element and repeat from step 1.

The roof and interior mouseover events don't trigger the loop because the tooltip box is outside the target element with the `data-tooltip` attribute.

You could try

1. Moving the tooltip box so it *cannot* appear under the mouse, or
2. Think of creative ways of using `mousenter` and `mouseleave` events on the anchor element that don't fire when hovering over the tooltip because it is a child of the anchor element, or
3. Turn off pointer events from tooltip elements:

```
.tooltip { 
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

---

Additional listeners used to verify the problem:

```
house.addEventListener("mouseover", e=>console.log("over"));
house.addEventListener("mouseout", e=>console.log("out"));
```

The additional delay caused by `console.log` did result in the tooltip  box being rendered and becoming visible in Firefox, but the log output definitely confirms the feed back loop in action.

Comment: I wish this was the issue. The problem is with assigning the style. Put this at the end of the mouseover listener:  
    `console.log("-"+(tooltip.offsetHeight+5)+"px"+" "+tooltip.style.top);`  
and hover over the link. It is driving me insane.  
  
Edit: it seems to do with `position:relative` on the parent element. If I change it to `position:absolute`, the text changes but the tooltip is positioned correctly. I still have no idea why.

Comment: On my system the  the value of `tooltip.offsetHeight` changes immediately after setting  `tooltip.top`, increasing from  40 to 58px in both Firefox and Edge. This can be explained by adding the offset height of the link (15px) plus the dropbox shadow width (3px) to the raw offset height of the tooltip (40px) to get  58px although I couldn't find this in standards. If this is not an issue, please edit the question to provide details of "it breaks" and cut down the code provided to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of how to reproduce the problem.